How to use the copilot key to do something in a window manager?
I use every single key on my laptop keyboard, with not one to spare.
I recently got a Thinkpad T14 gen 5, which has a copilot key where PrtSc used to be.  I was hoping to rebind the copilot key to be PrtSc (which I use heavily to resize windows), or at least map it to something (F23?) that I could intercept with my window manager for the same purposes.
Unfortunately, when I use showkey -s, pressing the copilot key gives 0xe0 0x5b 0x2a, and releasing 0xaa 0xe0 0xdb.  I verified that 0xe0 0x5b / 0xe0 0xdb is just what I get for pressing / releasing the left windows key, and 0x2a / 0xaa is what I get for pressing / releasing the left shift key.  So there doesn't seem to be a unique scan code for the copilot key.
If I use evtest, I get the following events from pressing/releasing copilot:
Event: time 1733647696.413560, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1733647696.413560, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1733647696.413560, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733647696.413794, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 2a
Event: time 1733647696.413794, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 1
Event: time 1733647696.413794, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733647696.413922, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 6e
Event: time 1733647696.413922, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733647696.519973, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 6e
Event: time 1733647696.519973, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733647696.520192, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 2a
Event: time 1733647696.520192, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 42 (KEY_LEFTSHIFT), value 0
Event: time 1733647696.520192, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733647696.520475, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1733647696.520475, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0

So there is some kind of event unique to pressing copilot (namely MSC_SCAN 0x6e), but this doesn't seem to yield a corresponding keyscan event I can put into a keyboard map to load with loadkeys.  If I could map that 0x6e event to F23, I could just have my window manager do the equivalent of the Print key on Win-Shift-F23, but I don't know how to do this.
My questions:

What is the relationship between the EV_MSC event values returned by evtest and the scan codes returned by showkey -s?
Is there some way to get the kernel to generate a key event from this EV_MSC 6e event?  Can I do this with a keymap and loadkeys, or is there something lower-level I need to do?
Are there any other ways to be able to intercept the copilot key in my window manager to resize windows?


It seems that the code 6e I get from evtest is a scancode that can be mapped to a keycode using the setkeycodes utility, and I don't understand what showkey -s is actually doing at all, but it's not outputting scan codes in the sense that setkeycodes/getkeycodes uses the term.  Running:
setkeycodes 6e 99

makes it so that the copilot key maps to PrtSc, and it even allows SysRq commands.  E.g., if you press Alt+(copilot, s) [i.e., press Alt, press copilot, release copilot, press s, release s, release Alt], the kernel will sync the disks.
When I went to check that SysRq functionality was working, it turns out journalctl -k actually had messages like "Unknown key pressed... Use 'setkeycodes 6e ' to make it known."  So there you have it.
Here's a systemd unit file (/etc/systemd/system/copilot-key.service) that you can enable to do this automatically:
[Unit]
Description=Map copilot key to Shift-Win-PrtSc
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setkeycodes 6e 99
ExecStop=/usr/bin/setkeycodes 6e 0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

